# VUE- Eventlistener within directive can't read function defined in methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js, data-visualization

I want my function defined in 'methods' to be excuted when 
my element is clicked. However, my eventlistener do something only when I use an anonymouse function like

```
el.addEventListener('click' function() {console.log('hi'))
```

When I set a function in methods, it spits error messages saying

> vue.js?3de6:634 [Vue warn]: Error in directive myDirective bind hook:
>   "ReferenceError: sizechange is not defined"
>
> found in
>
> --->  at /Users/soonkpaik/Downloads/Start 2/src/App.vue
>          
>   my code is as below.

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h1 v-myDirective:sizechange='{ inisize:100, finsize:500, color:"pink", blinkcolor:"red" }'>Directives Exercise!</h1>
                <!-- Exercise -->
                <!-- Build a Custom Directive which works like v-on (Listen for Events) -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
     directives:{  myDirective:{
                bind(el,binding,vnode){




                    let maincolor=binding.value.color;
                    let newcolor=binding.value.blinkcolor;        
                    let currentcolor=maincolor;

                    setInterval( ()=>{
                         currentcolor==newcolor? currentcolor=maincolor : currentcolor=newcolor

                         el.style.backgroundColor=currentcolor 
                    },500)

                     el.addEventListener('click',sizechange)






            }

        }
    },
       methods:{

        sizechange() {
            console.log('hi')

        }
    },
    }
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

What did I do wrong??
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is `sizechange()` function is not accessible directly inside [`bind hook function`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Hook-Functions) directly. You will need to refer to the current [vnode](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/vdom/vnode.js) context like:

```
export default {
  directives: {
    myDirective: {
      bind(el, binding, vnode) {
      
        // Your logic here...
                    
        var vm = vnode.context;
        el.addEventListener('click', vm.sizechange) // This works fine now
      }    
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sizechange() {
      console.log('hi')    
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: @palash Hi, it says [Vue warn]: Error in directive myDirective bind hook: "ReferenceError: vm is not defined"

Comment: How, is that possible vm is just defined above it like `var vm = vnode.context;`